# How can I swap underscore and dash keys without Karabiner?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

Unfortunately Karabiner is bugged for me, and freezes the system every 5 minutes or so.

I've managed to swap `~` on EU keyboard with

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000064,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035}]}'
UserKeyMapping:(
        {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771125;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771172;
    }
)
```

But I can't get the right UserKeyMapping for swapping `-` and `_` because they have the same key code.

I hear there's a `.keylayout`, maybe I can use that?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an "EU" keyboard?  What language exactly is your layout?  In any case, Ukelele easily lets you make custom keyboards that do what you want.  https://software.sil.org/ukelele/